# How filter categories with product in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got 3 collections

Product
Categories
Catalog

```
var CatalogueSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
contractNumber: {type: Number, unique: true},
globalRemise : {type: Number, default:0},
categories: [{
    fields : {type:ObjectId,ref:'Categorie'},
    remise : {type:Number, default:0}
}],
products: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }],
});

var CategorieSchema = {
id_categorie_sys: {type: Number, index: true},
name: {type: String}
};
```

and a collections Product with some attr

When i add some product into my catalog i want to add to the category of the product into my catalog to apply some discount price.
1 categorie have many product so i have to check if the categorie are already in my catalog or if i've to add in the catalog.

That's what i want to do.

I try to :
1. add the product into my catalog
2. make an array of the categorie product i added
3. check if the categorie if already in the catalog, if not i push it into the catalog

I'm using async.series to do this 
and if my array of categories in my catalog is empty async.forEach don't work with empty array

thanks everyone for help

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Maybe post your Product and Category schemas while you're at it? It's very hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Sure sorry i have to add some product into my catalog. When i add product into my catalog i want in my catalog only the categories of product wich are in my catalog like that i can apply a discount in the categorie. So what i'm trying to do it's to add only the categories of product who are in the catalog. I explain a bit more clear in my question what i've tried and what is my probleme. Because i think they are a different way much cleaner to do this but i don't know how start this.